# Botão "hamburger" não funciona

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-3

Alguém pode me dizer por que o botão não está funcionando? Era pra ele mostrar ao clicar nele, mas por algum motivo não está acontecendo nada. :(
Usando a classe "collapse navbar-collapse" eu consegui fazer o que eu queria, o menu, ficar escondido, mas na hora de chamar com o botão, ele simplesmente não funciona.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="CSS-projeto.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<div id="pai" class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-10">
    <div class="menu">
      <nav>
        <div class="navbar-default" id="navbardefault-cor">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <img class="img-responsive" id="imagemBBlogo2"  src="BBomParaTodos.png" alt="Banco Do Brasil Logo">
            <button id="botaoPosicao" type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
              <ul id="menu" class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="LogoPosicao">  <img class="img-responsive" id="imagemBBlogo"  src="BBomParaTodos.png" alt="Banco Do Brasil Logo"> </li>
                <li><a class="Entenda" href="#">ENTENDA</a></li>
                <li><a class="SemJuros" href="#">SEM JUROS</a></li>
                <li><a class="Quebra">|</a></li>
                <li id="telefoneC"><a class="tel" href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span> (99) 9999-9999</a></li>
                <li id="contatoLI"><a class="Contato" href="#Contato-Site" button  type="button"  data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">CONTATO</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Só pra confirmar, o bootstrap foi incluso corretamente, certo? Javascript e tudo o mais?

Comment: Incluiu o jQuery também? Na ordem, primeiro jquery.js depois bootstrap.js?

Comment: Olha, inclui sim, mas vou passar as linhas pra vocês conferirem, isso abaixo está dentro do <head>

Comment: Inclui na pergunta o <head> pra melhor visualização

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem dois problemas, a ordem do bootstrap e jquery esta errada:

```
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script href="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="CSS-projeto.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

E você usou `href=` dentro de script quando o correto deveria ser `src=`:

```
<script href="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"
```

O correto seria isto:

```
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- primeiro o jquery.js -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- depois vem o bootstrap.js -->
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="CSS-projeto.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Outro detalhe é que falta a tag `<body></body>`, mas não afeta a execução

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que no seu código o jQuery está incluso após o bootstrap.

```
<script href="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Notei que mais abaixo do código que mencionei, há outra inclusão do bootstrap. Se você incluir o bootstrap mais de uma vez no código, terá mais problemas ainda.

Da [documentação oficial do bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/):

> Also note that all plugins depend on jQuery (this means jQuery must be included before the plugin files)

"Perceba também que todos os plugins dependem do jQuery (isso significa que o jQuery deve ser incluso antes dos arquivos de plugins)". No seu caso, os plugins devem fazer parte do arquivo com o bootstrap minificado.

Corrigir a inserção dos arquivos deve resolver o seu problema.

Comment: Olha, eu atualizei o post com as dicas que deram no post, mas o botão ainda não funciona :(