# Toggle menu do bootstrap não está se expandindo

Tags: html5, twitter-bootstrap, django

Meu menu com toggle-icon, sendo usado exatamente como o da documentação exemplo do bootstrap4 simplesmente não se expande.

Tentei essa [solução](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/208709/bot%C3%A3o-hamburger-n%C3%A3o-funciona) mas não mudou nada. Atualmente o código está assim:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/giositeapp.css' %}"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>G M</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm shadow p-4 navbar-dark">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-link">Home</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogg" aria-controls="navbarTogg" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Alterna navegação">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogg">
                <ul class="navbar-nav flex-row ml-sm-auto d-none d-sm-flex">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">P</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">B</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">C</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

As tags com `{%%}` são por conta do Django, e, aparentemente, não são o problema pois o meu arquivo de css personalizado esta funcionando normalmente.

Comment: Bootstrap 3 ou 4 que vc está usando ?

Comment: Desculpa não falar, usando o 4

Comment: Inicialmente tentei só linkando, mas pra tirar a dúvida baixei os arquivos e fiz as referencias

Comment: Cara removi a resposta pq estava olhando o seu código e ele na verdade realmente parece ser do BS4 mesmo. acho que o problema deve ser outro...

Comment: Sim, é outro, mas tua resposta me ajudou a encontrar. Repare que eu tenho uma ul dentro da outra, o erro é na ul externa, ela esta bugando.

Comment: Eu havia usado essa ul externa para posicionar parte dos itens na direita da tela, mas aparentemente, isso também fez com que o toggle funcionasse de maneira duvidosa

Comment: é o d-none ali que impede que funcione, peguei haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para deixar registrado, o `d-none` era o problema. Funciona perfeitamente da seguinte forma (removendo-o):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm shadow p-4 navbar-dark">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-link">Home</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogg" aria-controls="navbarTogg" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Alterna navegação">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogg">
        <ul class="navbar-nav flex-row ml-sm-auto d-sm-flex">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">P</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">B</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">C</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: era isso mesmo eu estava achando que o problema era com o BTN e só depois vi que tinha uma UL dentro de outra UL e a UL de fora tinha display:none